# Custom Conditions for Mage_Rule + Different Entity Types

Tags: orders, invoice, rules

I have a client that is looking for a new rule-based module that will allow them to trigger various actions when order statuses are changed. While I'm fairly confident that I can code the event observers and the actual actions required (automatically creating an invoice when the order status is changed to X, etc.) I have no idea how to give my client a Mage_Rule style Conditions/Actions interface for this.

The first problem is that I only know of Mage_Rule being used for products. Catalog Price Rules, Shopping Cart Price Rules and Target Rules (EE only I believe) all use the catalog_product entity. None of these use Orders or Invoices or anything from that part of the Magento, so I have nothing to go off of.

The second problem is just the process of creating new conditions and new actions that Mage_Rule understands and can show to the user via the usual UI.

If anyone knows of existing tutorials out there, or even a plugin that does something similar that is licensed in a way that it will allow me to learn from their code, that would be awesome.

Thanks.